# i3's "for_window" equivalent in awesome-wm

Tags: awesome-wm

I'm trying to setup awesome + kde Plasma. However to complete my setup I wanted to kill the windows that have the "Desktop - Plasma" title, in i3 you would do `for_window [title="Desktop — Plasma"] kill;`. I wanted an awesome-wm equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does that i3 snippet do? Close all windows that have title "Desktop - Plasma"? If so:

```
for _, c in ipairs(client.get()) do
    if c.name == "Desktop - Plasma" then
        c:kill()
    end
end
```

Comment: That is indeed what it does. However your snippet is producing the following error : "attempt to call a table value"

Comment: Using ```ipairs(client.get())``` seems to have fixed it

Comment: Whoops, sorry for missing that part. `client.get()` returns a table containing all, well, clients. `ipairs` is the "lua way" to iterate over that table. I will update my answer.